# how to get the activated tab name using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tabs like a nav bar if i click on the tab the tab content will change i want to get the tab name of the activated tab how to do.
here is the code.
html:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

here is the reference [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs)

Comment: you are passing tabname as parameter, why dont you use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var activeTabname = "";

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    activeTabname = cityName;
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Use `activeTabname` whereever you need it.

**OR**

Find the active tab by checking the class `.active`

```
var activeTab = document.querySelector(".tabcontent.active");
```